# Prove that $\|u - v\| \ge \|u\| - \|v\|$ for any $u, v \in \mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Checking to see if the argument below works.

Consider $\|u - v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 - 2(u \cdot v) + \|v\|^2$,

by Cauchy-Schwarz: $\|u\|^2 - 2(u \cdot v) +\|v\|^2 \ge \|u\|^2 - 2(\|u\|  \|v\|) + \|v\|^2 = (\|u\| - \|v\|)^2$,

since $|u \cdot v| \le \|u\| \|v\| \to -2|u \cdot v| \ge -2(\|u\| \|v\|)$,

then taking the square roots, $|\|u - v\| \ge \|u\| - \|v\|$.

Comment: Another method is to note that $\| u \| = \|u - v + v \|$ and use the $\Delta$-inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct. But pay attention at the RHS, after taking square root, it is $ | \|u\| -\|v\| |$ then it implies the fact you want. It seem trivial, but careful is always important

Answer (score 0):

As MathMajor [pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585862/prove-that-u-v-ge-u-v-for-any-u-v-in-mathbb-rn/1585951#comment3228151_1585862), if you already have the triangle inequality
$$\|x + y\| \le \|x\| + \|y\|$$
at your disposal, you can get the desired statement from that.

My general strategy for this type of thing is to start by getting the desired inequality in a shape that looks like the triangle inequality:
$$\text{norm} \le \text{sum of two norms}.$$
In your case, we can do this by moving the $\|v\|$ to get
$$\|u\| \le \|u - v\| + \|v\|.$$
Now, observing that $u = (u - v) + v$, we can see that this really is a special case of the triangle inequality:
$$\|(u - v) + v\| \le \|u - v\| + \|v\|.$$

Comment: Thank you, Vectornaut. This helps a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, @numbers!